Which maths website is best for learning Mathematical logic and learning to deduce an explicit equation for patterns?
I was studying Maths in Brilliant and I am enjoying it. In addition, I especially admired a few pattern based courses. Therefore, is there any website that is specially dedicated to learning to solve patterns?
